# Jenkins could not checkout in in an automatically created pull request

Tags: python, git, jenkins, github, pygithub

I created a script in Python which automatically creates PR and the repo has Jenkins pipeline enabled.

Unfortunately Jenkins cannot handle PR created from script. Manually created PR is handled without troubles.
I have tried changing PR name, branch name, and commit message and nothing helps.
I guess it might have something to do with setting credentials by GIT_ASKPASS.
I am using [PyGithub](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) library.
When I am creating PR by hand I use git configuration with Windows Credentials Manager, however when PR is created from script, I pass only GIT token.

```
from github import Github

repo = Github(base_url=f"https://{HOST}/api/v3").get_repo(REPO_NAME)

### Adding commits and other stuff here ###

repo.create_pull(title=pr_name, body=body_message, head=branch_name, 
                 base="master")
```

Is it indeed problem with credentials, and if so how it can be handled?
[image]

Comment: Does the log say why it could not checkout the commit? Is it because the commit does not exist?

Comment: This commit exist, i check it now. There is not more log, only what i show in picture.